# JQuery get height of each previous element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to find a good solution to get the height of all the element above my target.

So loop the `prev()` function ! Any ideas on how I could deal with that ?

```
<div>
<div style="height:50px;width:100%"></div>
<div style="height:12px;width:100%"></div>
<div style="height:23px;width:100%"></div>
<div style="height:56px;width:100%"></div>
<div id="#mytarget"><p>HERE</p></div>
</div>

$('#mytarget').prev().each(function() {
    alert($(this).outerHeight());
});
```

and it will fires `["56","23","12","50"]`.

Comment: @MikeRobinson. No it's not... :) read my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`prev()` gives you only the *"immediately preceding sibling"* while
`prevAll` gives you *"all preceding siblings"*.

```
$('#mytarget').prevAll().each(function() {
     alert($(this).outerHeight());
});
```

And remove the `#` in the id:

`<div id="#mytarget">` => `<div id="mytarget">`

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/W6jSJ/)

**docs:**

[`prevAll`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/):

> Description: Get **all preceding siblings** of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

[`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/):

> Description: Get the **immediately preceding sibling** of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector

Comment: Thanks gdoron, I wasn't that far... :-)

Comment: @Jk_. I would even say you were close... :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/):

```
var result=[];
$('#mytarget').prevAll().each(function() {
    result.push($(this).outerHeight());
});
alert(result);
```

and also change

```
<div id="#mytarget"><p>HERE</p></div>
```

to:

```
<div id="mytarget"><p>HERE</p></div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JkDP6/